# Cheapest Twilio.com Product to Add Programmatic Audio To A Conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio.com for telephony, in the U.S.

I have an existing CONFERENCE, and I want to add arbitrary pre-recorded audio to it, at certain times.  I am aware of the "call out to yourself from yourself, then use PLAY or SAY" technique.

Is having another "call" going during the (at least two calls) conference really the best/**cheapest** way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not familiar with Twilio - are you asking what the financially cheapest method is, or the computationally cheapest?  If you are asking about the financially cheapest option, then I think SO might not be the right forum for this question (for example, SuperUser might make more sense).

Comment: Hiya, thanks for looking.  Yeah, I clarified the question to be Twilio.com, an API-driven telephony/SMS-and-more service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is the best and only way to achieve that feature right now.

However, that is going to change. Recently we added a feature called [Agent Conference](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/agent-conference-generally-available.html), which gives more power to the agent and supervisor within a contact centre. While it doesn't help now, [the announcement that the initial features for Agent Conference were out of beta](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/agent-conference-generally-available.html) also mentioned some future features that are coming, including:

> Conference announcements using `<Say>` or `<Play>` to everyone in a Conference or to individual participants

Keep an eye on the [Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog) for further announcements.